# Dart initialize class id with uuid if id not passed

Tags: dart

I'm making a class that has an ID field that is generated when the object is created.

```
const uuid = Uuid();

class Foo {
  final String id = uuid.v4();
  final String data;

  Foo(this.data);
}
```

I realised that this approach will cease to work because later I will have existing Ids in the database. Because of that I want to be able to set the Id in the constructor but generate it if the Id wasn't passed as an argument.

This led me to two solutions so far that I don't find satisfying.

#### Option 1: Just call the uuid function and pass a ready id beforehand

```
class Foo {
  final String id;
  final String data;

  Foo(this.id, this.data);
}

foo = Foo(Uuid().v4, "Some data");
```

This *works* but basically avoids the problem in its entirety. It would be nicer for the class to handle it automatically.

#### Option 2: Call uuid function in the body of the constructor

```
const uuid = Uuid();

class Foo {
  String? id;
  final String data;

  Foo({this.id, required this.data}) {
    id ??= uuid.v4();
  }
}
```

This also *works* but because the id field is first set to null and only then checked and replaced by the id we have to strip the final keyword from it. **This is very bad.**

Any idea what else I can try?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah alright I came up with an answer myself mid-question. Still, any further ideas and improvements are welcome!

```
class Foo {
  final String id;
  final String data;

  Foo({String? id, required this.data}) : id = id ?? uuid.v4();
}
```

We can just use a dummy variable to hold the null instead of inserting it directly into the final field.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, you should specify the type of the dummy variable because it will default to 'dynamic'

Comment: This should be declared as `Foo({String? id, this.data})`.  What you currently have is equivalent to `Foo({dynamic id, this.data})`.

Comment: Also, your example isn't quite legal. `data` would need to be declared as `String?` or the `Foo` constructor would have to use `required this.data`.

Comment: Ah sorry you're right, I do have that in the actual code but overlooked it while stripping it down for the example. I will edit my comment.